# What's the best way to convert dtsx packages to query a new server?

Tags: sql-server

We just moved our sql server to a hosting company, and now all my dtsx packaged don't work.

I know that in a specific query you can use

```
    use SecondDatabase
```

but is there a way to do that with the server, too?

**Goal:** Not have to rewrite my code and paste `[eih-dr01.db.org].livendb.dbo.` infront of every table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options come to mind:

If your dtsx packages are stored in the file system, you could use `POWERSHELL`  to read in each file, search and replace the connection string and rewrite the file.  Here is an example:

(Make sure you make a copy of the folder **BEFORE** running the Powershell script, just in case):

```
$DtsxFiles = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\uswsh\Documents\*.dtsx -rec
foreach ($file in $DtsxFiles)
{
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "localhost", "localhost1" } |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
}
```

If your packages are not stored in the file system, you could dynamically generate `CREATE SYNONYM` commands that would point to the new location.

```
CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[OriginalTable] FOR [RemoteServer].[RemoteDatabase].[RemoteSchema].[RemoteTable]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should open it using SQL Server Data Tools (microsoft developer environment).
This would allow you to specify a new connection string for this package.

Answer (score 1):

**Alias your connections to the new SQL Server using CLICONFG.EXE**

Don't to forget about Client Config (CLICONFG.EXE). Client Config acts as a host file pointer system for SQL Server connections by aliasing the old SQL Server name with the new one. *This is probably the fastest way to get up and running.*

It must be configured where on the SQL Server where the DTS packages are running. It essentially says anywhere you'd connect to server A, connect to Server B instead. Be warned though this is one stop shopping. All connections from A will be passed to Server B as shown in Figure A.

p.s. CLICONFG.EXE is built into the Windows O/S.

**Figure A:** *Cliconfg.exe allows you to alias your old connections to a new SQL Server*

[image]